# How to convert void statement into return statement returning a string?

Tags: java, apache-pig

All right so I tried converting the statement below into a return statement returning `finalString` but it always keeps telling me even though I do return `finalString` "this statement 
must return a variable of type String". I've tried putting `return finalString` in each individual if statement, in the for statement, outside of it but it doesn't work. I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions.
[UPDATE TO THE CODE] still doesn't work. The finalString value does not get modified by the
if statements, which is exactly what i want for it to do. I think that maybe the finalString value does not go through the if statements?

[code]

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class pLat//pig latin program
{

    /**
       * Method to test whether a character is a letter or not.
       * @param c The character to test
       * @return True if it's a letter
       */
      private static boolean isLetter(char c) {
        return ( (c >='A' && c <='Z') || (c >='a' && c <='z') );
      }


    ///////////////////////////////////////////
      private static String output(String input)//processes the word using basic rules including the q and u rule
      {

          //the string that will hold the value of the word entered by the user
          char s;//the first character of the string
          char m;
          int l = input.length();//determines the length of the string
          String endString;
          String startString;
          String finalString = ""; //the final output
          String mtr;
          String lowercase;//the entered string all converted to lowercase

          for(int k =0;k<l;k++)//checks all letters in order to see which is a vowel
          {

              s = input.charAt(k);

          if(s == 'q'|| s=='Q' && input.charAt(k+1)=='u')//if the first vowel is a "u" and the letter before it is a "q"
          {


                  endString = input.substring(0,k+2);//makes the endString also include u
                  endString = endString +"ay";
                  startString = input.substring(k+2,l);
                  finalString = startString + endString;
                  //System.out.println(finalString);
                  return finalString;


          }

          if(s=='a'||s=='e'||s=='i'||s=='o'||s=='u'||s=='A'||s=='E'||s=='I'||s=='O'||s=='U'||s=='y'||s=='Y')//if its a vowel or "y" than executes commands below
          {

              endString = input.substring(0, k);//gets the letters before the vowel
              endString = endString + "ay";
              startString = input.substring(k,l);//gets the letters after the vowel
              finalString = startString + endString;
              //System.out.println(finalString);//prints the final result which is the combination of startString with endString
              //stops code after doing the above
              return finalString;

          }


          else if(k==l-1)//if its the end of the word
          {
              finalString = "ERROR";
              return finalString;

          }

         }
          System.out.println(finalString);
          return finalString;
}///////////////////////////////////

//   public static void process(String input)//will take care of the punctuation
//   {
//       String latin = "";
//          int i = 0;
//          while (i<input.length()) {
//
//            // Takes care of punctuation and spaces
//            while (i<input.length() && !isLetter(input.charAt(i))) {
//              latin = latin + input.charAt(i);
//              i++;
//            }
//            latin = latin + output(input);
//            System.out.println(latin);
//          }
//          
//    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String str;//this will be the input string by the user
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);//this scanner will register the input value
        System.out.println("Enter a Word: ");
        str = scanner.next();//stores the input string

        output(str);//outputs it using basic gramatical rules

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see a return anywhere in your method - which is why you get the error. But even if you did have one, depending on where you place it it could be that it is not on all valid paths of execution.

Comment: @DaveRlz. OP is asking to convert this code into the one that returns a value, and that will need a change in return type. Currently the return type is `void`, so return statement is not needed.

Comment: @RohitJain - OK, missed that. In that case he should put the code in that he mentioned he has modified.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `return` statement in every `top-level` local block in your method. If you are not having it, then have a `return` statement, in every `block` inside that top-level block. And so on.

*Let's consider the simplest case of a set of* **`if - else if - else`**: -

You need to return your string from inside every `if` or `else` block, because only one of them will execute. So, if you miss a return statement in one of them, then its likely that, when that `block` is executed, then for sure, it will miss a return statement. Provided you are not having any return statement at the end of your `method`

So, basically, your return statement must come in every block, whose execution does not require the execution of any other block, and if those blocks cover all the possibility that a condition can have, then you don't need a return statement outside the blocks. Because one of those blocks will certainly execute.

Also, if those `blocks` does not cover every possibility of a certain condition `(like if you are not having an`else`for a set of if-else-if)`, then you must have a `return` statement outside those blocks. Because, if none of those blocks execute, then the `method` will miss the return statement.

**So, For e.g. you can see the set of below codes, covering most probable prossibilities: -**

```
public String returnString() {
        if (..) {
             return "someString";

        } else if (...) {
             return "someString";

        } else {
             return "someOtherString";
        }
       // return statement here is not needed. Because at least `else` will execute
}
```

So, at least one of the `if`, `else if` or `else` will always execute. So, you can add return statement in them, and leave the return statement outside those blocks.

However, had your last `else` block been an `else if`, then it might be possible that, none of the `blocks` execute. In that case, you must put a return statement after those blocks.

```
public String returnString() {
        if (..) {
             return "someString";

        } else if (...) {
             return "someString";

        } else if (...){
             return "someOtherString";
        }
       // return statement here is needed. 
       // Because its possible that none of the blocks in `if-else` set get executed.
}
```

Another possibility is that, rather than returning from every blocks, you can store the `return value` in some local variable, and at the end of all the blocks, return that `value` of local variable as the last statement in your method.

```
public String returnString() {
    int returnValue = 0;
    if (..) { returnValue = someValue; }
    else if(...) { returnValue = someOtherValue; }

    return returnValue;
}
```

**NOTE: -** You can utilize the last way in your code, as you are storing the `return value` in `finalString`. So, just return that string in the last line of your method.

Comment: The first two possibilities that you showed for some reason were not working so I went with the third on where you store the finalString in some local variable. But when i run the code it just the local variable value which is finalString = ""; (empty). So it doesn't return the processed value of finalString. This is a link to my new code. Take a look: http://www.4shared.com/office/eRMFPaCI/code.html

Comment: @user1781744. I cannot download your file from there. I don't have Premium account on `4shared`. You should post your code on some `opensource repository`.

Comment: You can just download it for free, there is a small download button, not very noticeable but it is there. I really appreciate you taking your time looking at my code.

Comment: @user1781744. Ok, got it. So what's the problem are you facing?

Comment: Basically I want my code to return finalString , as I am making a pig latin program for my AP Computer Science, but it returns nothing instead. Maybe it is because I specifies finalString = ""; , but that was in the beginning. The if statements are supposed to change finalString , but somehow it does not go through.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String output(String input)//processes the word using basic rules including the q and u rule
{

    //the string that will hold the value of the word entered by the user
    char s;//the first character of the string
    char m;
    int l = input.length();//determines the length of the string
    String endString;
    String startString;
    String finalString;//the final output
    String mtr;
    String lowercase;//the entered string all converted to lowercase

    for(int k =0;k<l;k++)//checks all letters in order to see which is a vowel
    {

        s = input.charAt(k);

    if(s == 'q'|| s=='Q' && input.charAt(k+1)=='u')//if the first vowel is a "u" and the letter before it is a "q"
    {


            endString = input.substring(0,k+2);//makes the endString also include u
            endString = endString +"ay";
            startString = input.substring(k+2,l);
            finalString = startString + endString;
            System.out.println(finalString);
            break;


    }

    if(s=='a'||s=='e'||s=='i'||s=='o'||s=='u'||s=='A'||s=='E'||s=='I'||s=='O'||s=='U'||s=='y'||s=='Y')//if its a vowel or "y" than executes commands below
    {

        endString = input.substring(0, k);//gets the letters before the vowel
        endString = endString + "ay";
        startString = input.substring(k,l);//gets the letters after the vowel
        finalString = startString + endString;
        System.out.println(finalString);//prints the final result which is the combination of startString with endString
        break;//stops code after doing the above

    }


    else if(k==l-1)//if its the end of the word
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        break;
    }
   }
   return finalString;
}
```

Here. Try this :-/

I don't know what you were trying to do. If you break out of the loop, you'll reach beyond the `for()` or `while()` or `do..while()` loop, which will be almost the end of the method in your case. I put the return finalString there and also changed the return type of the method `output` from `void` to `String`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not really an answer, Rohit Jain gave a good explanation on why your code doesn't work. From there you should be able to figure it out.

Looking at your code it struck me that this code is far more complex than it needs to be. My IDE (Eclipse) warns me about unused variables when I paste your code in. Having complex code is a cause for problems, as your case states.

I think in your case a little refactoring can help. And than you don't have the problem. To get you started, try separating the concerns of finding where to cut your String into two and the actual cutting. That should help. Maybe something like this:

```
private static int firstVowel(String input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char aChar = input.charAt(i);
        if ("aeiouyAEIOUY".indexOf(aChar) >= 0) {
            if (aChar == 'u' && i > 0 && Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i-1)) == 'q') {
                return i-1;
            }
            // else
            return i;
        }
    }
    // if we get here no vowel was found
    return -1;
}

// /////////////////////////////////////////
private static String output(String input)
{
    int firstVowel = firstVowel(input);
    if (firstVowel < 0) {
        return "ERROR";
    }
    // else
    String start = input.substring(firstVowel);
    String end = input.substring(0, firstVowel) + "ay";
    return start + end;
}// /////////////////////////////////


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str;// this will be the input string by the user
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);// this scanner will register
                                                // the input value
    System.out.println("Enter a Word: ");
    str = scanner.next();// stores the input string

    System.out.println(output(str));// outputs it using basic gramatical rules

}
```